# Oracle APEX Beginner - ORA-00900 Error When Running SQL Script

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm new to Oracle APEX and I'm trying to run a simple SQL script in my application to update some data in the database. Here's the script I'm using:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM Employee;
UPDATE Employee SET SAL = SAL * 100;
COMMIT;
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 797
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 782
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2035
```

I searched on the internet to get a solution. But I couldn't find anything Similler.
I want to know why this is'nt working.

Comment: This is not an Oracle SQL syntax. Please check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr01001.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're running that piece of code in SQL Workshop (looks like you are), note that:

- there's no `start transaction` in Oracle (as you were already told; this is not MySQL)
- commands can be run one-at-a-time. In other words, you can have several statements in the window, but if you just push the <kbd>Run</kbd> button, you'll get an error.

  Mark a command (with a mouse, for example) and then run it

  [image]
- finally, `commit` is useless in this context. If you execute it, you'll get

  > Commit statement not applicable. All statements are automatically committed.

Comment: BEGIN
  DECLARE
    max_salary NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(SAL) INTO max_salary FROM Employee;

    UPDATE Employee SET SAL = SAL * 2;

    COMMIT;
  END;
END;


I just found it on the internet. And it works. I don't know why. I am actually very new to these things

Comment: That's a **PL/SQL** block. Statements you originally posted are pure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`START TRANSACTION;` is not a valid statement in Oracle.

Transactions are started implicitly with the first statement you use and you cannot explicitly declare a transaction.

Your remaining statements are, individually, valid SQL statements in Oracle's dialect.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I7DvOwzu)

> ```sql
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE
>     max_salary NUMBER;
>   BEGIN
>     SELECT MAX(SAL) INTO max_salary FROM Employee;
>     UPDATE Employee SET SAL = SAL * 2;
>     COMMIT;
>   END;
> END;
> ```
>
> And it works. I don't know why.

If you are using an editor where you can ony run single statements then you have used a PL/SQL anonymous block to wrap multiple SQL statements into a single PL/SQL statement and your editor is running the single PL/SQL statement and passing it to the database which is using the PL/SQL engine to run each of the SQL statements.

*Note: You do not need the initial `BEGIN` and the final `END`.*

Comment: BEGIN
  DECLARE
    max_salary NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(SAL) INTO max_salary FROM Employee;

    UPDATE Employee SET SAL = SAL * 2;

    COMMIT;
  END;
END;


I just found it on the internet. And it works. I don't know why. I am actually very new to these things

Comment: @AlMohaiminFarabi Updated.